# How do I generate all permutations of a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

How do I generate all the permutations of a list? For example:

```
permutations([])
[]

permutations([1])
[1]

permutations([1, 2])
[1, 2]
[2, 1]

permutations([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 757, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) from the **standard library**:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3]))
```

---

Adapted from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/252178/) is a demonstration of how `itertools.permutations` might be implemented:

```
def permutations(elements):
    if len(elements) <= 1:
        yield elements
        return
    for perm in permutations(elements[1:]):
        for i in range(len(elements)):
            # nb elements[0:1] works in both string and list contexts
            yield perm[:i] + elements[0:1] + perm[i:]
```

A couple of alternative approaches are listed in the documentation of `itertools.permutations`. Here's one:

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, n-r, -1)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

And another, based on `itertools.product`:

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    for indices in product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if len(set(indices)) == r:
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: This and other recursive solutions have a potential hazard of eating up all the RAM if the permutated list is big enough

Comment: They also reach the recursion limit (and die) with large lists

Comment: bgbg, dbr: Its using a generator, so the function itself won't eat up memory. Its left to you on how to consume the iterator returned by all_perms (say you could write each iteration to disk and not worry about memory). I know this post is old but I'm writing this for the benefit of everyone who reads it now. Also now, the best way would be to use itertools.permutations() as pointed out by many.

Comment: Not just *a* generator. It's using nested generators, which each yield to the previous one up the call stack, in case that's not clear. It uses O(n) memory, which is good.

Comment: This solution yields 12 permutations instead of the normal 6, for [1, 2, 3].

Comment: PS: I fixed it, with `for i in range(len(elements))` instead of `for i in range(len(elements)+1)`. In fact, the singled-out element `elements[0:1]` can be in `len(elements)` different positions, in the result, not `len(elements)+1`.

Comment: This solution is much faster than tzwenn's or mine, which is based on successively selecting the first element of the output permutation and recursively appending the permutations of the remaining elements (factor of 3 or 4 on elements). I am not yet sure why, though.

Comment: PS: this solution is much faster because permutating N elements only requires the calculations of all permutations of N-1 elements *once* (compared to N times for our solutions).

Comment: In python 2.7, this does not work for various variants of lists

Comment: Sadly we can't use a "size" parameter to only generate permutations of a give size.

Comment: `yield perm[:i] + elements[0:1] + perm[i:]` can be `yield perm[:i] + elements[0] + perm[i:]`?

Comment: list(set(itertools.permutations([1, 1, 2])), if you have repetitive elements in the list.

Comment: @BorisGorelik . I am currently using itertools.permutations but it crashes my instance on AWS with it has more than 10 elements. How would one overcome this challenge?

Answer (score 373):

For [Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.6.html) onwards:

```
import itertools
itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3])
```

This returns as a generator.  Use `list(permutations(xs))` to return as a list.

Comment: Notice that there exists an `r` parameter, e.g. `itertools.permutations([1,2,3], r=2)`, which will generate all possible permutations selecting 2 elements: `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]`

Answer (score 359):

First, import `itertools`:

```
import itertools
```

#### Permutation (order matters):

```
print(list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4], 2)))

[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4),
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

#### Combination (order does NOT matter):

```
print(list(itertools.combinations('123', 2)))

[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
```

#### Cartesian product (with several iterables):

```
print(list(itertools.product([1,2,3], [4,5,6])))

[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6),
(2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6),
(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

#### Cartesian product (with one iterable and itself):

```
print(list(itertools.product([1,2], repeat=3)))

[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2),
(2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: +1! Docs link: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 65):

```
def permutations(head, tail=''):
    if len(head) == 0:
        print(tail)
    else:
        for i in range(len(head)):
            permutations(head[:i] + head[i+1:], tail + head[i])
```

called as:

```
permutations('abc')
```

Comment: Why print tail and then return None? Why not return tail instead? Why not return anything anyways?

Comment: @bugmenot123 you probably want all of the final tails rather than just tail, this is done easily by adding a `perms=[]` parameter to the function, appending to it on every `print` and having a final `return perms`

Answer (score 40):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def perm(a, k=0):
   if k == len(a):
      print a
   else:
      for i in xrange(k, len(a)):
         a[k], a[i] = a[i] ,a[k]
         perm(a, k+1)
         a[k], a[i] = a[i], a[k]

perm([1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

As I'm swapping the content of the list it's required a mutable sequence type as input. E.g. `perm(list("ball"))` will work and `perm("ball")` won't because you can't change a string.

This Python implementation is inspired by the algorithm presented in the book *Computer Algorithms by Horowitz, Sahni and Rajasekeran*.

Comment: I assume k is the length or permutations. For k = 2 outputs [1, 2, 3]. Shouldn't it be  (1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 1)
(3, 2) ??

Comment: k is the index of the element you want to swap

Comment: NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: 7 years later, how would I return a list of lists of all the permuted lists?  Also, can this be done iteratively?

Comment: this is done easily by adding a perms=[] parameter to the function, appending to it on every print and having a final return perms

Answer (score 24):

This solution implements a generator, to avoid holding all the permutations on memory:

```
def permutations (orig_list):
    if not isinstance(orig_list, list):
        orig_list = list(orig_list)

    yield orig_list

    if len(orig_list) == 1:
        return

    for n in sorted(orig_list):
        new_list = orig_list[:]
        pos = new_list.index(n)
        del(new_list[pos])
        new_list.insert(0, n)
        for resto in permutations(new_list[1:]):
            if new_list[:1] + resto <> orig_list:
                yield new_list[:1] + resto
```

Answer (score 21):

Regular implementation (no yield - will do everything in memory):

```
def getPermutations(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        return [array]
    permutations = []
    for i in range(len(array)): 
        # get all perm's of subarray w/o current item
        perms = getPermutations(array[:i] + array[i+1:])  
        for p in perms:
            permutations.append([array[i], *p])
    return permutations
```

Yield implementation:

```
def getPermutations(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        yield array
    else:
        for i in range(len(array)):
            perms = getPermutations(array[:i] + array[i+1:])
            for p in perms:
                yield [array[i], *p]
```

The basic idea is to go over all the elements in the array for the 1st position, and then in 2nd position go over all the rest of the elements without the chosen element for the 1st, etc. You can do this with **recursion**, where the stop criteria is getting to an array of 1 element - in which case you return that array.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me _> *ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2,)* , for this line: `perms = getPermutations(array[:i] + array[i+1:])`

Comment: @RK1 what was the input?

Comment: I'm passing in a `numpy` array _> `getPermutations(np.array([1, 2, 3]))`, I see it works for a list, just got confused as the func arg is `array` :)

Comment: @RK1 glad it works :-) list is a keyword in python, so it's usually not a good idea to call your parameter a keyword, as it will "shadow" it. So I use the word array, as this is the actual functionality of the list that I'm using - their array like manner. I guess if I would write documentation I would clarify it. Also I believe that basic "interview" questions should be solved without external packages, like numpy.

Comment: Haha that's true, yeah was trying to use it with `numba` and got greedy with speed so tried to use it exclusively with `numpy` arrays

Comment: Is that asterisk supposed to be there in this line?  

permutations.append([array[i], *p])

I removed it and the code ran fine.

Comment: @dgundersen yes it is crucial there. The colon is needed to unpack the array. Otherwise you will get a very messy result (an array of array of array....)

Answer (score 20):

In a functional style

```
def addperm(x,l):
    return [ l[0:i] + [x] + l[i:]  for i in range(len(l)+1) ]

def perm(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return [[]]
    return [x for y in perm(l[1:]) for x in addperm(l[0],y) ]

print perm([ i for i in range(3)])
```

The result:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 17):

The following code is an in-place permutation of a given list, implemented as a generator. Since it only returns references to the list, the list should not be modified outside the generator.
The solution is non-recursive, so uses low memory. Work well also with multiple copies of elements in the input list.

```
def permute_in_place(a):
    a.sort()
    yield list(a)

    if len(a) <= 1:
        return

    first = 0
    last = len(a)
    while 1:
        i = last - 1

        while 1:
            i = i - 1
            if a[i] < a[i+1]:
                j = last - 1
                while not (a[i] < a[j]):
                    j = j - 1
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] # swap the values
                r = a[i+1:last]
                r.reverse()
                a[i+1:last] = r
                yield list(a)
                break
            if i == first:
                a.reverse()
                return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in range(5):
        for a in permute_in_place(range(1, n+1)):
            print a
        print

    for a in permute_in_place([0, 0, 1, 1, 1]):
        print a
    print
```

Answer (score 17):

A quite obvious way in my opinion might be also:

```
def permutList(l):
    if not l:
            return [[]]
    res = []
    for e in l:
            temp = l[:]
            temp.remove(e)
            res.extend([[e] + r for r in permutList(temp)])

    return res
```

Answer (score 13):

```
list2Perm = [1, 2.0, 'three']
listPerm = [[a, b, c]
            for a in list2Perm
            for b in list2Perm
            for c in list2Perm
            if ( a != b and b != c and a != c )
            ]
print listPerm
```

Output:

```
[
    [1, 2.0, 'three'], 
    [1, 'three', 2.0], 
    [2.0, 1, 'three'], 
    [2.0, 'three', 1], 
    ['three', 1, 2.0], 
    ['three', 2.0, 1]
]
```

Comment: While it technically produces the desired output, you're solving something that could be O(n lg n) in O(n^n) - "slightly" inefficient for large sets.

Comment: @James: I am a little confused by the O(n log n) that you give: the number of permutations is n!, which is already much larger than O(n log n); so, I can't see how a solution could be O(n log n). However, it is true that this solution is in O(n^n), which is much larger than n!, as is clear from Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 12):

I used an algorithm based on the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system)- For a list of length n, you can assemble each permutation item by item, selecting from the items left at each stage. You have n choices for the first item, n-1 for the second, and only one for the last, so you can use the digits of a number in the factorial number system as the indices. This way the numbers 0 through n!-1 correspond to all possible permutations in lexicographic order.

```
from math import factorial
def permutations(l):
    permutations=[]
    length=len(l)
    for x in xrange(factorial(length)):
        available=list(l)
        newPermutation=[]
        for radix in xrange(length, 0, -1):
            placeValue=factorial(radix-1)
            index=x/placeValue
            newPermutation.append(available.pop(index))
            x-=index*placeValue
        permutations.append(newPermutation)
    return permutations

permutations(range(3))
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

This method is non-recursive, but it is slightly slower on my computer and xrange raises an error when n! is too large to be converted to a C long integer (n=13 for me). It was enough when I needed it, but it's no itertools.permutations by a long shot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Although posting the brute force method has its merits, if you don't think your solution is better than the accepted solution, you probably shouldn't post it (especially on an old question that already has so many answers).

Comment: I was actually looking for a brute-force non-library approach, so thanks!

Comment: I found it useful too!

Answer (score 10):

Note that this algorithm has an `n factorial` time complexity, where `n` is the length of the input list

Print the results on the run:

```
global result
result = [] 

def permutation(li):
if li == [] or li == None:
    return

if len(li) == 1:
    result.append(li[0])
    print result
    result.pop()
    return

for i in range(0,len(li)):
    result.append(li[i])
    permutation(li[:i] + li[i+1:])
    result.pop()
```

Example:

```
permutation([1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 8):

One can indeed iterate over the first element of each permutation, as in tzwenn's answer. It is however more efficient to write this solution this way:

```
def all_perms(elements):
    if len(elements) <= 1:
        yield elements  # Only permutation possible = no permutation
    else:
        # Iteration over the first element in the result permutation:
        for (index, first_elmt) in enumerate(elements):
            other_elmts = elements[:index]+elements[index+1:]
            for permutation in all_perms(other_elmts): 
                yield [first_elmt] + permutation
```

This solution is about 30 % faster, apparently thanks to the recursion ending at `len(elements) <= 1` instead of `0`.
It is also much more memory-efficient, as it uses a generator function (through `yield`), like in Riccardo Reyes's solution.

Answer (score 7):

This is inspired by the Haskell implementation using list comprehension:

```
def permutation(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [[x] + ys for x in list for ys in permutation(delete(list, x))]

def delete(list, item):
    lc = list[:]
    lc.remove(item)
    return lc
```

Answer (score 6):

For performance, a numpy solution inspired by [Knuth](http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc2b.pdf), (p22) :

```
from numpy import empty, uint8
from math import factorial

def perms(n):
    f = 1
    p = empty((2*n-1, factorial(n)), uint8)
    for i in range(n):
        p[i, :f] = i
        p[i+1:2*i+1, :f] = p[:i, :f]  # constitution de blocs
        for j in range(i):
            p[:i+1, f*(j+1):f*(j+2)] = p[j+1:j+i+2, :f]  # copie de blocs
        f = f*(i+1)
    return p[:n, :]
```

Copying large blocs of memory saves time - 
it's  20x faster than `list(itertools.permutations(range(n))` :

```
In [1]: %timeit -n10 list(permutations(range(10)))
10 loops, best of 3: 815 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit -n100 perms(10) 
100 loops, best of 3: 40 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: shameless plug by package author. :)

The [trotter](https://pypi.org/project/trotter/) package is different from most implementations in that it generates pseudo lists that don't actually contain permutations but rather describe mappings between permutations and respective positions in an ordering, making it possible to work with very large 'lists' of permutations, as shown in [this demo](https://permutation-products.netlify.com/) which performs pretty instantaneous operations and look-ups in a pseudo-list 'containing' all the permutations of the letters in the alphabet, without using more memory or processing than a typical web page.

In any case, to generate a list of permutations, we can do the following.

```py
import trotter

my_permutations = trotter.Permutations(3, [1, 2, 3])

print(my_permutations)

for p in my_permutations:
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
A pseudo-list containing 6 3-permutations of [1, 2, 3].
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Your package have a limit between 400 - 500 elements.

Comment: @ecdani Thanks for your interest in this library! If each atom in the Milky Way galaxy spontaneously turned into a new Milky Way galaxy, and each of the new atoms did that again, we still wouldn't have as many atoms as there are permutations of 500 elements. Having said that, if you up your system's maximum recursion level a bit, the library can easily represent permutations of 1,000 or more elements, and searching and lookup are still pretty instantaneous. If you like, post an issue at the [trotter repository page](https://github.com/ram6ler/python-trotter/issues).

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use the builtin methods such as:

```py
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3]))
```

you can implement permute function yourself

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable


def permute(iterable: Iterable[str]) -> set[str]:
    perms = set()

    if len(iterable) == 1:
        return {*iterable}

    for index, char in enumerate(iterable):
        perms.update([char + perm for perm in permute(iterable[:index] + iterable[index + 1:])])

    return perms


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(permute('abc'))
    # {'bca', 'abc', 'cab', 'acb', 'cba', 'bac'}
    print(permute(['1', '2', '3']))
    # {'123', '312', '132', '321', '213', '231'}
```

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of recursion:

```
>>> import copy
>>> def perm(prefix,rest):
...      for e in rest:
...              new_rest=copy.copy(rest)
...              new_prefix=copy.copy(prefix)
...              new_prefix.append(e)
...              new_rest.remove(e)
...              if len(new_rest) == 0:
...                      print new_prefix + new_rest
...                      continue
...              perm(new_prefix,new_rest)
... 
>>> perm([],['a','b','c','d'])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'd', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'c', 'd', 'b']
['a', 'd', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'd', 'c', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
['b', 'a', 'd', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a', 'd']
['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']
['c', 'a', 'd', 'b']
['c', 'b', 'a', 'd']
['c', 'b', 'd', 'a']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['c', 'd', 'b', 'a']
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'a', 'c', 'b']
['d', 'b', 'a', 'c']
['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
['d', 'c', 'a', 'b']
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 4):

**ANOTHER APPROACH (without libs)**

```
def permutation(input):
    if len(input) == 1:
        return input if isinstance(input, list) else [input]

    result = []
    for i in range(len(input)):
        first = input[i]
        rest = input[:i] + input[i + 1:]
        rest_permutation = permutation(rest)
        for p in rest_permutation:
            result.append(first + p)
    return result
```

**Input can be a string or a list**

```
print(permutation('abcd'))
print(permutation(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
```

Comment: This does not work for a list with integers, eg. `[1, 2, 3]` returns `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`

Comment: @RK1, u can try this `print(permutation(['1','2','3']))`

Answer (score 3):

```
from __future__ import print_function

def perm(n):
    p = []
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        p.append(i)
    while True:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            print(p[i], end=' ')
        print("")
        i = n - 1
        found = 0
        while (not found and i>0):
            if p[i]<p[i+1]:
                found = 1
            else:
                i = i - 1
        k = n
        while p[i]>p[k]:
            k = k - 1
        aux = p[i]
        p[i] = p[k]
        p[k] = aux
        for j in range(1,(n-i)/2+1):
            aux = p[i+j]
            p[i+j] = p[n-j+1]
            p[n-j+1] = aux
        if not found:
            break

perm(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algorithm that works on a list without creating new intermediate lists similar to Ber's solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/108651/184528.

```
def permute(xs, low=0):
    if low + 1 >= len(xs):
        yield xs
    else:
        for p in permute(xs, low + 1):
            yield p        
        for i in range(low + 1, len(xs)):        
            xs[low], xs[i] = xs[i], xs[low]
            for p in permute(xs, low + 1):
                yield p        
            xs[low], xs[i] = xs[i], xs[low]

for p in permute([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print p
```

You can try the code out for yourself here: http://repl.it/J9v

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm is the most effective one, it avoids of array passing and manipulation in recursive calls, works in Python 2, 3:

```
def permute(items):
    length = len(items)
    def inner(ix=[]):
        do_yield = len(ix) == length - 1
        for i in range(0, length):
            if i in ix: #avoid duplicates
                continue
            if do_yield:
                yield tuple([items[y] for y in ix + [i]])
            else:
                for p in inner(ix + [i]):
                    yield p
    return inner()
```

Usage:

```
for p in permute((1,2,3)):
    print(p)

(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def pzip(c, seq):
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        for i in range(len(item)+1):
            result.append(item[i:]+c+item[:i])
    return result


def perm(line):
    seq = [c for c in line]
    if len(seq) <=1 :
        return seq
    else:
        return pzip(seq[0], perm(seq[1:]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Generate all possible permutations

I'm using python3.4:

```
def calcperm(arr, size):
    result = set([()])
    for dummy_idx in range(size):
        temp = set()
        for dummy_lst in result:
            for dummy_outcome in arr:
                if dummy_outcome not in dummy_lst:
                    new_seq = list(dummy_lst)
                    new_seq.append(dummy_outcome)
                    temp.add(tuple(new_seq))
        result = temp
    return result
```

Test Cases:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
#lst = ["yellow", "magenta", "white", "blue"]
seq = 2
final = calcperm(lst, seq)
print(len(final))
print(final)
```

Comment: This (so far) is the most understandable solution for me (non-math head). I can list chars I want to permutate and this works! What is the logic to add duplicates characters to permutations? **Example:** `def calcperm(arr, size, dupes):` where `dupes` are the allowed numbers of duplicates to allow for each permutation.

Answer (score 2):

I see a *lot* of iteration going on inside these recursive functions, not exactly *pure* recursion...

so for those of you who cannot abide by even a single loop, here's a gross, totally unnecessary fully recursive solution

```
def all_insert(x, e, i=0):
    return [x[0:i]+[e]+x[i:]] + all_insert(x,e,i+1) if i<len(x)+1 else []

def for_each(X, e):
    return all_insert(X[0], e) + for_each(X[1:],e) if X else []

def permute(x):
    return [x] if len(x) < 2 else for_each( permute(x[1:]) , x[0])


perms = permute([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 2):

To save you folks possible hours of searching and experimenting, here's the non-recursive permutaions solution in Python which also works with Numba (as of v. 0.41):

```
@numba.njit()
def permutations(A, k):
    r = [[i for i in range(0)]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in A for b in r if (a in b)==False]
    return r
permutations([1,2,3],3)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

To give an impression about performance:

```
%timeit permutations(np.arange(5),5)

243 µs ± 11.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
time: 406 ms

%timeit list(itertools.permutations(np.arange(5),5))
15.9 µs ± 8.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
time: 12.9 s
```

So use this version only if you have to call it from njitted function, otherwise prefer itertools implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway we could use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/) library , also support for multiset permutations

```
import sympy
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
t = [1,2,3]
p = list(multiset_permutations(t))
print(p)

# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer is highly inspired by [Get all permutations of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210142/get-all-permutations-of-a-numpy-array/41210450)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
def permutation(flag, k =1 ):
    N = len(flag)
    for i in xrange(0, N):
        if flag[i] != 0:
            continue
        flag[i] = k 
        if k == N:
            print flag
        permutation(flag, k+1)
        flag[i] = 0

permutation([0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: @Pathros well, the code above is for Python 2. For Python 3, please use `range()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192158/nameerror-global-name-xrange-is-not-defined-in-python-3

Answer (score 1):

This is the asymptotically optimal way O(n*n!) of generating permutations after initial sorting.

There are n! permutations at most and hasNextPermutation(..) runs in O(n) time complexity

In 3 steps,

1. Find largest j such that a[j] can be increased
2. Increase a[j] by smallest feasible amount
3. Find lexicogrpahically least way to extend the new a[0..j]

```py
'''
Lexicographic permutation generation

consider example array state of [1,5,6,4,3,2] for sorted [1,2,3,4,5,6]
after 56432(treat as number) ->nothing larger than 6432(using 6,4,3,2) beginning with 5
so 6 is next larger and 2345(least using numbers other than 6)
so [1, 6,2,3,4,5]
'''
def hasNextPermutation(array, len):
    ' Base Condition '
    if(len ==1):
        return False
    '''
    Set j = last-2 and find first j such that a[j] < a[j+1]
    If no such j(j==-1) then we have visited all permutations
    after this step a[j+1]>=..>=a[len-1] and a[j]<a[j+1]

    a[j]=5 or j=1, 6>5>4>3>2
    '''
    j = len -2
    while (j >= 0 and array[j] >= array[j + 1]):
        j= j-1
    if(j==-1):
        return False
    # print(f"After step 2 for j {j}  {array}")
    '''
    decrease l (from n-1 to j) repeatedly until a[j]<a[l]
    Then swap a[j], a[l]
    a[l] is the smallest element > a[j] that can follow a[l]...a[j-1] in permutation
    before swap we have a[j+1]>=..>=a[l-1]>=a[l]>a[j]>=a[l+1]>=..>=a[len-1]
    after swap -> a[j+1]>=..>=a[l-1]>=a[j]>a[l]>=a[l+1]>=..>=a[len-1]

    a[l]=6 or l=2, j=1 just before swap [1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2] 
    after swap [1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] a[l]=5, a[j]=6
    '''
    l = len -1
    while(array[j] >= array[l]):
        l = l-1
    # print(f"After step 3 for l={l}, j={j} before swap {array}")
    array[j], array[l] = array[l], array[j]
    # print(f"After step 3 for l={l} j={j} after swap {array}")
    '''
    Reverse a[j+1...len-1](both inclusive)

    after reversing [1, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    '''
    array[j+1:len] = reversed(array[j+1:len])
    # print(f"After step 4 reversing {array}")
    return True

array = [1,2,4,4,5]
array.sort()
len = len(array)
count =1
print(array)
'''
The algorithm visits every permutation in lexicographic order
generating one by one
'''
while(hasNextPermutation(array, len)):
    print(array)
    count = count +1
# The number of permutations will be n! if no duplicates are present, else less than that
# [1,4,3,3,2] -> 5!/2!=60
print(f"Number of permutations: {count}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is over 12 old) with existing answers (this one has _40_). How does this answer improve upon what's already here? Note also that the question is about _Python_. How does an answer in Java help?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also rotate

```
def perm_rotate(elements):
    if len(elements) <= 1:
        yield elements
        return

    for _ in range(len(elements)):
        for perm in perm_rotate(elements[1:]):
            yield [elements[0]] + perm
        elements = rotate(elements)

def rotate(numbers):
    return [numbers[-1]] + numbers[: len(numbers)-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My Python Solution:

```
def permutes(input,offset):
    if( len(input) == offset ):
        return [''.join(input)]

    result=[]        
    for i in range( offset, len(input) ):
         input[offset], input[i] = input[i], input[offset]
         result = result + permutes(input,offset+1)
         input[offset], input[i] = input[i], input[offset]
    return result

# input is a "string"
# return value is a list of strings
def permutations(input):
    return permutes( list(input), 0 )

# Main Program
print( permutations("wxyz") )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def permutation(word, first_char=None):
    if word == None or len(word) == 0: return []
    if len(word) == 1: return [word]

    result = []
    first_char = word[0]
    for sub_word in permutation(word[1:], first_char):
        result += insert(first_char, sub_word)
    return sorted(result)

def insert(ch, sub_word):
    arr = [ch + sub_word]
    for i in range(len(sub_word)):
        arr.append(sub_word[i:] + ch + sub_word[:i])
    return arr


assert permutation(None) == []
assert permutation('') == []
assert permutation('1')  == ['1']
assert permutation('12') == ['12', '21']

print permutation('abc')
```

Output: ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

def permutations(nums):
    ans = [[]]
    cache = Counter(nums)

    for idx, x in enumerate(nums):
        result = []
        for items in ans:
            cache1 = Counter(items)
            for id, n in enumerate(nums):
                if cache[n] != cache1[n] and items + [n] not in result:
                    result.append(items + [n])

        ans = result
    return ans
permutations([1, 2, 2])
> [[1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def permuteArray (arr):

    arraySize = len(arr)

    permutedList = []

    if arraySize == 1:
        return [arr]

    i = 0

    for item in arr:

        for elem in permuteArray(arr[:i] + arr[i + 1:]):
            permutedList.append([item] + elem)

        i = i + 1    

    return permutedList
```

I intended to not exhaust every possibility in a new line to make it somewhat unique.

Answer (score 0):

````
from typing import List
import time, random

def measure_time(func):
    def wrapper_time(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        return res, end_time - start_time

    return wrapper_time


class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int], method: int = 1) -> List[List[int]]:
        perms = []
        perm = []
        if method == 1:
            _, time_perm = self._permute_recur(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1, perms)
        elif method == 2:
            _, time_perm = self._permute_recur_agian(nums, perm, perms)
            print(perm)
        return perms, time_perm

    @measure_time
    def _permute_recur(self, nums: List[int], l: int, r: int, perms: List[List[int]]):
        # base case
        if l == r:
            perms.append(nums.copy())

        for i in range(l, r + 1):
            nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
            self._permute_recur(nums, l + 1, r , perms)
            nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]

    @measure_time
    def _permute_recur_agian(self, nums: List[int], perm: List[int], perms_list: List[List[int]]):
        """
        The idea is similar to nestedForLoops visualized as a recursion tree.
        """
        if nums:
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                # perm.append(nums[i])  mistake, perm will be filled with all nums's elements.
                # Method1 perm_copy = copy.deepcopy(perm)
                # Method2 add in the parameter list using + (not in place)
                # caveat: list.append is in-place , which is useful for operating on global element perms_list
                # Note that:
                # perms_list pass by reference. shallow copy
                # perm + [nums[i]] pass by value instead of reference.
                self._permute_recur_agian(nums[:i] + nums[i+1:], perm + [nums[i]], perms_list)
        else:
            # Arrive at the last loop, i.e. leaf of the recursion tree.
            perms_list.append(perm)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = [random.randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(3)]
    sol = Solution()
    # perms, time_perm = sol.permute(array, 1)
    perms2, time_perm2 = sol.permute(array, 2)
    print(perms2)
    # print(perms, perms2)
    # print(time_perm, time_perm2)
```
````

Comment: Some explanation would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone fancies this ugly one-liner (works only for strings though):

```
def p(a):
    return a if len(a) == 1 else [[a[i], *j] for i in range(len(a)) for j in p(a[:i] + a[i + 1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def permutate(l):
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        for y in l[i + 1:]:
            yield x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list(permutate(list('abcd'))))
    print(list(permutate([1, 2, 3, 4])))

#[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
#[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Beautiful and simple!

Comment: .....but wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solving with recursion, iterate through elements, take i'th element, and ask yourself: 'What is the permutation of rest of items` till no more element left.

I explained the solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7GE7psS2b4

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self,nums:List[int])->List[List[int]]:
        res=[]
        def dfs(nums,path):
            if len(nums)==0:
                res.append(path)
            for i in range(len(nums)):
                dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:],path+[nums[i]])
        dfs(nums,[])
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the user wants to keep all permutations in a list, the following code can be used:

```
def get_permutations(nums, p_list=[], temp_items=[]):
    if not nums:
        return
    elif len(nums) == 1:
        new_items = temp_items+[nums[0]]
        p_list.append(new_items)
        return
    else:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            temp_nums = nums[:i]+nums[i+1:]
            new_temp_items = temp_items + [nums[i]]
            get_permutations(temp_nums, p_list, new_temp_items)

nums = [1,2,3]
p_list = []

get_permutations(nums, p_list)
```

Answer (score -3):

for Python we can use itertools and import both permutations and combinations to solve your problem

```
from itertools import product, permutations
A = ([1,2,3])
print (list(permutations(sorted(A),2)))
```